# labbook/scrbook new chapter not on separate page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, koma-script, labbook

I am using labbook document class which relies on scrbook. It starts a new page for each chapter, which I don't want to happen. Is there a way to force it to procede with a new chapter on the same page where the previous ends?

I tried

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

but it did not work.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{labbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\labday{Monday}
First day in the lab.
\labday{Tuesday}
Second day in the lab.

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Works for me, so you'll have to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @lockstep: Sorry, I now added it to the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `\labday` uses `\addchap` (`KOMA-Script`'s unnumbered version of `\chapter`), you have to patch this command. I added a `\par` at the start of the changed definition in case (as in your example) no `\par` or blank line is added before `\labday` in the document body.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{labbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\addchap}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{\par}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\labday{Monday}
First day in the lab.
\labday{Tuesday}
Second day in the lab.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!
Is it actually possible to keep the heading with the chapter title? (in case of several chapters on one page it would be the first one)

Comment: Try `\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{headings}`.

Comment: This patch does not work anymore because of internal changes of KOMA-Script some years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Since 2015 KOMA-Script provides command `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the style of the sectioning command `\chapter` from `style=chapter` to `style=section`:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{chapter}
```

Note that style `section` needs a value for `indent` while style `chapter` does not know this option.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{labbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{chapter}

\begin{document}
\labday{Monday}
First day in the lab.
\labday{Tuesday}
Second day in the lab.
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]